# Cx_Oracle Python Pandas to SQL Database Connection Failed Error

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, cx-oracle

With the code below, I am attempting to connect read a CSV and append it to an existing Oracle database. The trouble is, I keep getting this error for the inserting to the Oracle table part:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host 
or object does not exist
```

My tnsnames.ora file is working just fine in every other instance (i.e. connecting to Oracle via Tableau or pandas.read_sql).

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle as cx
pwd=input('Enter Password for server:')
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://schema:'+pwd+'@server:1521/table')
conn = cx.Connection("schema/"+pwd+"@server")
df=pd.read_csv(r'path\data.csv',encoding='Latin-1',index_col=0)
df.to_sql(conn,engine,if_exists='append')
```

**Update:**

I needed to exclude the 'con' argument from df.to_sql() because connection information was already contained in 'engine'.

Comment: That error usually means that `server` is a host name (or FQDN) that can't be resolved. What do you actually have for that? And which command is actually throwing the error? The `/table` in the `create_engine()` looks odd; and shouldn't the `cx.Connection` be using `"schema/"+pwd+"@server:1521/service_name"`?

Comment: For my server name, I have the name of the server I use in SQL developer (with some help from tnsnames.ora so I don't have to enter a long name). It has worked before with Pandas.read_sql (without the service name). It's the last line of code that is throwing the error. I put '/table' at the end because I followed the format here:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Comment: I tried modifying both create_engine and cx.Connection (by using the format you mentioned instead) to no avail.

Comment: So I got some help from a colleague and now they seem to be fine (it turns out I was using the wrong database name). However, there is a new error and so I have a new question as a result. I've posted it above.